# How to redirect to action on custom page within admin section

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, redirect, actions

Currently I'm developing(well at least trying to;) plugin which will handle custom gallery of images. I stumbled upon one problem though. I'll try to picture it.

I've created custom menu page on which I can edit gallery options as well as I can add/delete/edit elements of gallery. I did add link to every gallery item so after choosing 'edit' I could be able to modify element.

```
function column_rls_name($item) {
  $actions = array(
            'edit'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&rls_element=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['rls_name']),
        );
  return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $item['rls_name'], $this->row_actions($actions) );
}
```

Problem begins when 'edit' on element is clicked. It should redirect to settings page.

Here I have a question. What is the best way to do this. Are there any helper functions/hooks/etc out there which would help in creating such page (and detect redirection).

Of course I could do it in function responsible for displaying main gallery options like:

```
if($_GET['action']=='edit')
    //then do sth
else
    //display main gallery options
```

but I don't think it's the best way.

I would like to know which functions I could use, from creating custom link, creating custom page and registering them.

What method should be used when action=edit is triggered. How to spot it was requested on the actual page. How to show then page related to the content.

```
wp-admin/options-general.php?page=rls_logotypes&action=edit&rls_element=element1
```

Comment: _Problem begins when 'edit' on element is clicked. It should redirect to settings page._ Where is the problem? Where redirect it now? What is the best way to do what? Create a redirection? Or create a propper link to an admin page? Please clearify your question. What does `$this->row_actions($actions)` do?

Comment: It does redirect (changes link from options-general.php?page=rls_logotypes to options-general.php?page=rls_logotypes&action=edit&book=element1) but my question here is which helper functions(if they exist) should I use to detect this redirection and show another page. My question is should i detect it manually or could I use some functions/hooks. row_actions is just a function from WP_List_Tables which inserts a div in to the table row with links.

Comment: You do not want to show another page and you do not want to do a redirection. You are on page _rls_logotype_ which is a subpage of _options-general.php_
What you want to do is to detect an action. A redirect is if you go from site A to site B (e.g. from dashboard.php to options.php).
You can only use `$_REQUEST` (or `$_GET` / `$_POST`) to detect an action in your url-parameters.

Comment: Multi-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13774231/1287812

Answer (score 1):

Get the url of a specific admin page (e.g. the settings page (options-general.php)):

```
admin_url( 'options-general.php' )
```

[Codex admin_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url)

Adding query arguments to an url:

```
$params = array(
    'page'          => $_REQUEST['page'],
    'action'        => 'edit',
    'rls_element'   => $item['rls_name']
);

$url = add_query_arg( $params, $org_url );
```

[Codex add_query_arg()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)

Put a and b together:

```
$params = array(
    'page'          => $_REQUEST['page'],
    'action'        => 'edit',
    'rls_element'   => $item['rls_name']
);

$url = add_query_arg( $params, admin_url( 'options-general.php' ) );
```

Now we can create links:

```
public function column_rls_name( $item ){

    $actions = array(
    'edit'  => $this->create_admin_link(
                        array(
                            'text'      => 'Edit',
                            'action'    => 'edit',
                            'item'      => $item['rls_name']
                        )
                )
    );

    return sprintf( '%1$s %2$s', $item['rls_name'], $this->row_actions( $actions ) );

}

public function create_admin_link( $args = array() ){

    $params = array(
        'page'          => $_REQUEST['page'],
        'action'        => $args['action'],
        'rls_element'   => $args['item']
    );

    $url = add_query_arg( $params, admin_url( 'options-general.php' ) );

    return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $url, $args['text'] );

}
```

Comment: Thanks! So one element of puzzle is solved.Thx for explaining thing with redirection. So as far as I understand 'edit' should be detected in a function responsible for displaying main _rls_logotypes_ page.